# Resetting noUiSlider after using updateOptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I am using noUISlider's updateOptions function to update the sliders start and range options. After updating the values and interacting with the slider, I am using noUISlider.reset() to reset the slider. However, when using reset it is resetting to the values set during the create() state and NOT the updateOptions values. Has anyone come across a similar issue before? Why isn't reset() updating the slider to new `start` values?

**Code**

```
    var slider = document.getElementById('price-slider');

    if (slider.noUiSlider == undefined)
    {
        noUiSlider.create(slider, {
            start: [min_total_price, max_total_price],
            connect: true,
            range: {
                'min': min_total_price,
                'max': max_total_price
            },
            step: 1,
            format: {
                to: function (value) {
                    return Math.floor(value);
                },
                from: function (value) {
                    return Math.floor(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
            start: [min_total_price, max_total_price],
            range: {
                'min': min_total_price,
                'max': max_total_price
            }
        });
    }



    $(".reset").click(function() {
           slider.noUiSlider.reset(); // Why is this not resetting to updateOptions values?

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `reset`, why need to reset it after you've just drawn (initialized) it?

Comment: I updated post. The reset should happen after clicking on button

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for `reset` to go back to values that were updated on an existing slider instance. I think `reset` is doing exactly what's supposed to do.

I don't get what reset is meant to do in your case, revert the latest update, but keep previous updates? You can store the min/max values in some global variable(s) or window properties, in this way, you have complete control over them, you assign the values whenever you want and drop the values whenever you want. On click on that button just update the existing slider instance to the values you have stored.